# Cross-contract call failed with TransferFailed

Tags: ink, cross-contract-call

After instantiating a contract using the `CreateBuilder` as shown [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/files#diff-84af1add043372bf3be8123a2d3477b5f1d436cc0dbbf322c0bcd3c99249adb2R45).
If I then try to call the contract using `CallBuilder` as shown [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/files#diff-84af1add043372bf3be8123a2d3477b5f1d436cc0dbbf322c0bcd3c99249adb2R69) and use `#[ink(message, payable)]` in the callee message of the contract being called as shown [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/files#diff-16556624fa5972a5348e9b062eb7965d702c694b78d5190aa7097dc66d70a79bR35) it only compiles if I use `.transferred_value(0)` with a transfer value of `0`.

But if I follow the ink! cross-contract documentation [here](https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling#builders) and change the transfer value to a non-zero value as they use in their examples, it always results in `TransferFailed` error. Note: I also get the error when just using the Contracts Ref Approach without the Builders Approach.

Why can't I pass a non-zero value to `transferred_value`?